# Winrt Is it possible to support design mode with string resources (resw)?

Tags: xaml, resources, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am using string resources for supporting some languages in my app.
In windows store apps it's a little bit different, I am using resw file (instead of resx).

And using the x:Uid I get the string, but the problem is that I don't see the value in the design mode (only in the runtime).

I can write Text="TheStringValue" also, but it's not really what I want, because I want it to be dynamic on design mode. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean Debug or Design Mode, because I never had any issue with the debug mode using resw.

Comment: Oh yes, design mode...

Comment: I don't believe there is, though you may try adding to the pages constructor a method which checks for design mode, then goes through and manually sets the values of all elements via a ResourceLoader. I don't know if this will work though, as it's likely the Resources are loaded at runtime.

Comment: I did not find a solution to that issue either. Actually, I always put a default wording in Xaml addressing design time only (because it is replaced at runtime with resources).

Comment: Old question but unanswered. It works for me in visual studio/blend 2013. I add the x:Uid="Something" to my Textblock, *I remove the Text from the Textblock". And after building it works in design mode too